# Can object properties be used as function parameters?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class with several Boolean properties:

```
class aTest {
  String name;
  bool twoGroups;
  bool continuous;
  bool parametric;
  bool covariates;
  bool paired;

  aTest(
      {this.name,
      this.twoGroups,
      this.continuous,
      this.parametric,
      this.covariates,
      this.paired});
} //end aTest
```

I also have a list with instances of `aTest`:

```
List<aTest> testList = [
  aTest(
      name: "independent samples t-test",
      twoGroups: true,
      continuous: true,
      parametric: true,
      covariates: false,
      paired: false),
//followed by a bunch of similar objects
]
```

Elsewhere in my app I filter the `List<aTest>` with procedures like:

```
void isParametric(bool value) {
  List<aTest> newList = [];
  for (aTest test in testList) {
    if (test.parametric == value || test.parametric == null) {
      newList.add(test);
    }
  }
  testList = newList;
}

void isTwoGroups(bool value) {
  List<aTest> newList = [];
  for (aTest test in testList) {
    if (test.twoGroups == value || test.twoGroups == null) {
      newList.add(test);
    }
  }
  testList = newList;
}
```

(I don't know whether this is the best way to filter and remove objects from the `List.`) All that differs among these procedures is an object property, e.g., `test.parametric` and `test.twoGroups` in the code above.

Is there a way to refactor the code? Something like
`void filter (aBooleanPropertyGoesHere, bool value)`

Comment: Pass a function? https://code-maven.com/slides/dart-programming/passing-functions-as-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply filter with the lists with one liner by where method.

```
    var parametricList = testList.where((i) => (i.continuous && i.parametric == null)).toList()
```

```
   var twoGroupsList = testList.where((i) => (test.twoGroups == value || test.twoGroups == null)).toList()
```

Something like this https://dartpad.dev/79a7e9aa5882af745b6ff2cb55815921

For detailed explanation check out the [documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/Iterable/where.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response. +1 for including not only a documentation link but also an explanatory dartpad demo.